# Why setImmediate() execute before fs.readFile() in Nodejs Event Loop's works?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I have read a lot of related documents.But I still can't understand how it works.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const now = Date.now();

setTimeout(() => console.log('timer'), 10);
fs.readFile(__filename, () => console.log('readfile'));
setImmediate(() => console.log('immediate'));
while(Date.now() - now < 1000) {
}
```

---

```
const now = Date.now();

setImmediate(() => console.log('immediate'));
setTimeout(() => console.log('timer'), 10);
while(Date.now() - now < 1000) {
}
```

I think the first piece of code should log:

```
readfile
immediate
```

And the second piece of code logs.

```
timer
immediate
```

I think it is ok.

Problem：
I don't understand why the first piece of code logs

```
immediate
readfile
```

I think that the file has been read completely and its callback function enqueue  I/O callbacks phase's queque after 1 second.

And then I think event loop will move to `timers(none)`,`I/O callbacks(fs.readFile's callback)`,`idle/prepare(none)`,`poll(none)`,`check(setImmediate's callback)`and finally `close callbacks(none)` in order, but result is that `setImmediate()` still run first.

Comment: there's no real statement of 1) expected result and importantly, 2) the problem/error. the `while` loop looks like it's missing the body also.

Comment: What do you want to achieve, what's your problem? Please clarify.

Comment: Logs are so because `fs.readfile` is asynchronous, it doesn't blocks the I/O. Let the `setTimeout` execute. When the file is read it logs `readfile`.

Comment: `setImmediate` is also asynchronous，I think it should be called before `fs.readfile`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The behavior you see is because there are multiple types of queues in the event loop and the system runs events in an order according to their type.  It is not just one giant event queue where everything runs in FIFO order based on when it was added to the event queue.  Instead, it likes to run all the events of one type (up to a limit), advance to the next type, runs all those and so on.

And, I/O events are only added to their queue at one specific point in the cycle so they are forced into a particular order.  This is the reason that `setImmediate()` callback executes before the `readFile()` callback even though both are ready to go when the `while` loop is done.

> And then I think event loop will move to timers(none),I/O callbacks(fs.readFile's callback),idle/prepare(none),poll(none),check(setImmediate's callback)and finally close callbacks(none) in order, but result is that setImmediate() still run first.

The issue is that the I/O callbacks stage of the event loop runs I/O callbacks that are already in the event queue, but they don't get put into the event queue automatically when they are done.  Instead, they are only put into the event queue later in the process in the `I/O poll` step (see diagram below).  So, the first time through the I/O callbacks stage, there are no I/O callbacks to run yet, thus you don't get the `readfile` output when you think you would.

But, the `setImmediate()` callback is ready the first time through the event loop so it gets to run before the `readFile()` callback.

This delayed addition of I/O callbacks is likely the explanation for why you are surprised that the `readFile()` callback happens last instead of before the `setImmediate()` callback.

Here's what happens when the `while` loop finishes:

1. When the while loop finishes, it starts with timer callbacks and sees that the timer is ready to run so it runs that.
2. Then, it goes to run any I/O callbacks that are already there, but there are none yet.  The I/O callback from the `readFile()` has not been collected yet.  It will get collected later in this cycle.
3. Then, it goes through several other stages and gets to I/O poll.  There is collects the `readFile()` callback event and puts it in the I/O queue (but does not run it yet).
4. Then, it goes to the checkHandlers phase where it runs the `setImmediate()` callback.
5. Then, it starts the event loop over again.  There are no timers so it goes to I/O callbacks and it finally finds and runs the `readFile()` callback.

---

So let's document what actually happens in your code in a little more detail for those that are not as familiar with the event loop process.  When you run this code (with timing added to the output):

```
const fs = require('fs')

let begin = 0;
function log(msg) {
    if (!begin) {
        begin = Date.now();
    }
    let t = ((Date.now() - begin) / 1000).toFixed(3);
    console.log("" + t + ": " + msg);
}

log('start program');

setTimeout(() => log('timer'), 10);
setImmediate(() => log('immediate'));
fs.readFile(__filename, () => log('readfile'));

const now = Date.now();
log('start loop');
while(Date.now() - now < 1000) {}
log('done loop');
```

You get this output:

```
0.000: start program
0.004: start loop
1.004: done loop
1.005: timer
1.006: immediate
1.008: readfile
```

I've added timing in seconds relative to when the program started so you can see when things are executed.

Here's what happens:

1. Timer is started and set for 10ms from now, other code continues to run
2. `fs.readFile()` operation is started, other code continues to run
3. `setImmediate()` is registered into the event system and its event is in the appropriate event queue, other code continues to run
4. `while` loop starts looping
5. During the `while` loop, the `fs.readFile()` finishes its work (running in the background).  It's event is ready, but not yet in the appropriate event queue (more on this later)
6. `while` loop finishes after 1 second of looping and this initial sequence of Javascript is done and returns back to the system
7. The interpreter now needs to get the "next" event from the event loop.  But, all types of events are not treated equally.  The event system has a particular order that it processes different types of events in the queue.  In our case, here, the timer event gets processed first (I will explain this in the following text).  The system checks to see if any timers have "expired" and are ready to call their callback.  In this case it finds that our timer has "expired" and is ready to go.
8. Timer callback is called and we see the console message `timer`.
9. There are no more timers so the event loop advances to its next stage.  The next stage of the event loop is to run any pending I/O callbacks.  But, there are no pending I/O callbacks in the event queue yet.  Even though the `readFile()` is done by now, it is not yet in the queue (explanation coming).
10. Then, the next step is to gather any I/O events that have finished and get them ready to run.  Here, the `readFile()` event will be collected (though not run yet) and put into the I/O event queue.
11. Then the next step is to run any `setImmediate()` handlers that are pending.  When it does that, we get the output `immediate`.
12. Then, the next step in the event process is to run any close handlers (there are none here to run).
13. Then, the event loop starts over again by checking for timers.  There are no pending timers to run.
14. Then, the event loop runs any pending I/O callbacks.  Here the `readFile()` callback runs and we see `readfile` in the console.
15. The program has no more events to wait for so it executes.

The event loop itself is a series of queues for different types of events and (with some exceptions), each queue is processed before moving onto the next type of queue.  This causes groupings of events (timers in one group, pending I/O callbacks in another group, `setImmediate()` in another group and so on).  It is not a strict FIFO queue among all types.  Events are FIFO within a group.  But, all pending timer callbacks (up to some limit to keep one type of event from hogging the event loop indefinitely) are processed before other types of callbacks.

You can see the basic structure in this diagram:

[image]

which comes from [this very excellent article](https://jsblog.insiderattack.net/handling-io-nodejs-event-loop-part-4-418062f917d1).  If you really want to understand all this stuff, then read this referenced article several times over.

What initially surprised me is why the `readFile` always comes at the end.  This is because even though the `readFile()` operation is done, it is not immediately put in the queue.  Instead, there's a step in the event loop where completed I/O events are collected (to be processed in the next cycle through the event loop) and `setImmediate()` events are processed at the end of the current cycle before the I/O events that were just collected.  This makes the `readFile()` callback go after the `setImmediate()` callback, even though they both are ready to go during the while loop.

And, further, it doesn't matter which order you execute the `readFile()` and the `setImmediate()`.  Because they both are ready to go before the `while` loop is done, their execution order is determined by the sequencing though the event loop as it runs different types of events, not by exactly when they finished .

---

In your second code block, you remove the `readFile()` and put the `setImmediate()` before the `setTimeout()`.  Using my timed version, that would be this:

```
const fs = require('fs')

let begin = 0;
function log(msg) {
    if (!begin) {
        begin = Date.now();
    }
    let t = ((Date.now() - begin) / 1000).toFixed(3);
    console.log("" + t + ": " + msg);
}

log('start program');

setImmediate(() => log('immediate'));
setTimeout(() => log('timer'), 10);

const now = Date.now();
log('start loop');
while(Date.now() - now < 1000) {}
log('done loop');
```

And, it generates this output:

```
0.000: start program
0.003: start loop
1.003: done loop
1.005: timer
1.008: immediate
```

The explanation is similar (shortened a bit this time since lots of detail was explained earlier).

1. `setImmediate()` is registered into the appropriate queue.
2. `setTimeout()` is registered into the timer queue.
3. The while loop runs for its 1000ms
4. The code finishes executing and returns control back to the system
5. The system starts at the top of the event logic which starts with timer events.  The timer we started earlier is done now so it runs its callback and logs `timer`.
6. With no more timers, the event loop runs through several other types of event queues until it gets to where it runs `setImmediate()` handlers and it logs `immediate`.

---

If, you have multiple items schedule to start within an I/O callback such as this:

```
// timeout_vs_immediate.js
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile(__filename, () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('timeout');
  }, 0);
  setImmediate(() => {
    console.log('immediate');
  });
});
```

Then, you get slightly different behavior because the `setTimeout()` and `setImmediate()` will be scheduled when the event loop is in a different part of its cycle.  In this particular example, the `setImmediate()` will always execute BEFORE the timer so the output will be:

```
 immediate
 timeout
```

In the flow chart above, you can see where the "run completed I/O handlers" step is.  Because the `setTimeout()` and `setImmediate()` calls will be scheduled from within an I/O handler, they are going to be scheduled at the "Run completed I/O handlers" phase of the event loop.  Follow the flow of the event loop, the `setImmediate()` will get serviced in the "check handlers" phase before the event loop gets back around to service timers.

If the `setImmediate()` and `setTimeout()` are scheduled at a different point in the event loop, then the timer may fire before `setImmediate()` which is what happens in the earlier example.  So, the relative timing of the two depends upon what phase the event loop is in when the functions are called.

Comment: Hi jfriend00, thank you for your explanation.

But after I put some printf into libuv event loop, I am sure that the callback of  js readFile is executed inside the uv__io_poll function.

```
sss
```

Comment: Hi jfriend00, thank you for your explanation.

But after I put some printf into libuv event loop, I am sure that the callback of  js readFile is executed inside the uv__io_poll function, not inside uv__run_pending.

The reason why 'readfile' appears after the 'immediate' is that the readFile operation can't be done within one uv__io_poll call.

Comment: @RueianOneecom - I'm not sure exactly what you're saying, but `readFile()` would definitely take more than one step of the event loop to complete because it will consist of multiple async operations (opening the file, reading the file, closing the file) which will take multiple events to schedule in the event loop.

Comment: `14. Then, the event loop runs any pending I/O callbacks. Here the readFile() callback runs and we see readfile in the console.`. @jfriend00 - However, after injecting some `printf` calls into libuv event loop, I am sure that the readFile() callback runs in the `IO Poll` stage, not in the `pending IO callbacks` stage.

Comment: @RueianOneecom - OK, good data.  I think what I need to factor into the logic is that `readFile()` by itself is actually a series of at least 3 async operations.  I'll have to see if I can get my head back into this (it made my brain hurt the first time trying to follow all this).

Comment: Agree with @jfriend00. fs.readFile() is actually an asynchronous call to read a file, rather a call to queue deferred task using either setTimeout() or setImmediate(). 

Node.js, when processing the script, queues both of these tasks in their respective Timers and Check phase queues. But I/O callback would be added when the fs.readFile() call return, and hence would be processed in next tick.

So in the first tick itself, there were no I/O callbacks to be executed, but in the next phase of event loop i.e., check phase, one immediate callback() was ready to be executed.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Also, "Poll" phase is not just for polling completed I/O events. If you read official documentation - https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/ , it has been mentioned that while polling for new I/O events(queued by Kernel), existing completed I/O callbacks may get processed at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('timer'), 10);                
fs.readFile(__filename, () => console.log('readfile'));    
setImmediate(() => console.log('immediate'));               

while(Date.now() - now < 1000) {
}
```

**Explanation**

1. The `setTimeout` schedules to be put in an event loop after 10ms.
2. Asynchronous file reading starts.
3. The non-standard `setImmediate` schedules to show a console output breaking long processes.
4. A one-second blocking loop runs. Nothing in the console yet.
5. `setImmediate` prints `immediate` console message during the loop.
6. File reading ends and the callback is executed even after the `while` loop is 
   over. The console output `readfile` is there now.
7. Finally, the console message `timer` is printed after about 10 secs later.

**Things to note**

- None of above commands (except the loop) are synchronous. They
  schedule something and immediately proceed to the next command.
- The callback functions are called only after the current blocking
  execution is over.
- Timeout commands are not guaranteed to be executed at the designated
  interval. The guarantee is that they will run anytime **after** the
  interval.
- `setImmediate` is very experimental.

Comment: There are several mistakes in your answer: 1)it's 10 microseconds not 10 second 2)`setImmediate()'s callback` is also called after `while` loop is over while.(because `immediate` and `readfile` logs together and file is small.)

Comment: Edited for milliseconds. Please refer MDN to see that setImmediate fires during loops.

Comment: I have read this entire answers and comments.Finally why **I/o Phase(readFile()) ** executes after **Check Phase(setImmediate)** because of **I/o Callbacks** will not be executed in the current cycle of the event loop Even though it gets ready to execute.It will execute in the next cycle of the event loop.Correct me If'm Wrong....

Comment: I am having 2nd doubt =>    In the **next cycle** of the event loop **readFile() callback** will be executed in which phase either in **Pending I/O Phase or I/O Poll phase.**